# Can I host non-adult content on a .xxx domain

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

For example, I can I put up a personal blog on `user58113.xxx`?

What are the legitimate challenges that I might face:

- Will Google treat my site as adult even though it is not?
- Will many ISPs block me by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely host non-adult content on a .xxx domain, including a personal blog. You will face some challenges with being blocked by content filters (i.e workplace and school content filters) and possibly search engines. Search engines typically have settings for blocking adult content and if you use that top level domain, prepare to be subject to being blocked when users are filtering adult content.

There is a great example of this on the wikipedia page and the kite.xxx domain that is used for an "extreme kite surfing sports" website, hosting no adult content.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.xxx